# Consolas font too thin

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code, text-editor, consolas

When I use my other computer the consolas font is appearing way thinner than it used to be. Here are 2 images to show the differences:

[image: Font before]

and

[image: Font now]

I tried changing the fontWeight and size in my text editors but it still look different.
(It tried different text editors and the font is different for all of them)
Thanks for your help !

Comment: If it happens with different text editors, it's clearly not a problem with VSCode. That means your post is off-topic here. Try [su] instead.

Comment: First picture appears to come from a high resolution display. When fonts are rendered to cover a different number of physical pixels it's very unlikely than they look identical. Whatever, many operating systems have a control panel to fine-tune the font rendering. If you happen to be using Windows you can find some details [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Typography/ClearTypeInfo.aspx).